# How to keep the clean url displayed in browser and not the dirty redirected one?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers

I have decided to create clean url links for my products for SEO purposes and so the customer can better remember a link. I have been researching for hours, but not completely understanding the clean and dirty url redirect concept. You would think there would be more simplier documentation available on this subject.

I have my .htaccess file configured as below and is working perfectly to take a user typed clean url or clean link such as www.example.com\Category\Subcategory\ and redirect it to a .php file for accessing a MySQL table and display the product information.

What I can't figure out is how to keep the clean url displayed to the user in their browser and not show the dirty or redirected url? Is that accomplished in the .htaccess file?

To make it clearer:

If a customer types: www.example.com\shoes\running, .htaccess redirects the clean url to subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=$1&s=$2 which basically process the clean url and looks up the appropriate information and displays it dynamically.

But now the customer sees www.example.com\subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=$1&s=$2 in their browser.

Instead I would like them to see the clean url www.example.com\shoes\running.

.htaccess file contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# do not do anything for already existing file, symbolic link or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# redirect category/subcategory to lookup page
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=$1&s=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

Comment: You're `mod_rewrite` is redirecting to a php file which is dynamically generating output based on the parameters you pass it. At what point does the URL become "dirty?"

Comment: So you want to re-direct the other way around too, so that if someone access `/subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=$1&s=$2`, they'll see the clean URL?

Comment: @BenM That is correct.

Comment: Why someone would and could enter for example: `http://example.com/subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=5&s=9` in the browser's address bar, in the first place? You have very special visitors, no doubt, they like the really hard way to access the site pages.

Comment: @faa These urls are already indexed by search engines and I want to clean them because a lot of customers bookmark or return to these pages and I want something that they can easily remember and identify.

Comment: My point is when `http://example.com/subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=5&s=9` is redirected just to replace it with `http://example.com/5/9/` in the browser's address bar, it is mapped silently back to itself: `http://example.com/subcat_lookup_clean.php?c=5&s=9`, according to your rules. So, in my humble opinion, that operation has no purpose except wasting resources and loosing performance. Google will also end up in the initial URL, but after being redirected twice which is everything but good for SEO.

Comment: @faa I understand your point. I think it would be best if I just clean the urls within the site and just let google pick up the new clean urls instead of being concerned with the old 'dirty' ones already linked.

Comment: Google will keep going to the resources regardless if their links are "pretty" or "ugly". You shouldn't be concerned about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CORRECTED .htaccess below with solution that works perfectly.**

You can demo it here: http://www.tiedandtrue.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# if redirected to url cleaner, redirect to actual lookup file and
# these lines will keep the clean url visible in the browser
RewriteRule ^cat_url_cleaner.php ./cat_lookup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^subcat_url_cleaner.php ./subcat_lookup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^subsubcat_url_cleaner.php ./subsubcat_lookup.php [L]

# do not do anything if already existing file, symbolic link or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# redirect clean url (/category) for processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./cat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./cat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1 [L]

# redirect clean url (/category/subcategory) for processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./subcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./subcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]

# redirect clean url (/category/subcategory/subsubcategory) for processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./subsubcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2&ss=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./subsubcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2&ss=$3 [L]
```